# Standard visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk

My uncle is inviting me to the UK for a short holiday during my long vacation. I'm a university student. He is paying for my trip. When filling the application form, I was asked the reason why he is paying for my trip but I don't know what to write. Can you please help me?

Comment: Why is your uncle paying for your trip?

Comment: And if you don't know, ask your uncle.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions / comments. Putting on hold.